# Change padding of vuetify v-expansion-panel-content

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have multiple casceded v-expansion-panels to visualize a folder sturcture. Like in this example with items and innerItems

```
  <v-expansion-panels
     accordion
     focusable
  >
     <v-expansion-panel
        v-for="(item, x) in items"
        :key="x"
     >
        <v-expansion-panel-header> {{ item.header }}</v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content class="v-expansion-panel-content">
           <v-expansion-panels>
             <v-expansion-panel
                v-for="(innerItem, y) in innerItems"
                :key="y"
             >
                <v-expansion-panel-header> {{ innerItem.header }} </v-expansion-panel-header>
                <v-expansion-panel-content> {{ innerItem.content }} </v-expansion-panel-content>
               </v-expansion-panel>
            </v-expansion-panels>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
     </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
```

So I get this

[image]

But I need the inner expansion-panel to be on the right side like this

[image]

I achieved this by editing the .v-expansion-panel-content__warp in the browser editor (just to get what I want it to look like) but how can I get access to this self generated div/css-class

[image]

There is already a question regarding the panel-header ([Stylization vuetify component v-expansion-panel__header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967794/stylization-vuetify-component-v-expansion-panel-header)) but I dont get this question or the answer...

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction or had the same problem and can show me a way to fix this!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to complete the css path to make it work in a component
`.v-expansion-panel-content .v-expansion-panel-content__wrap {}`

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. I fixed it like in the answer below! Thanks anyway for the quick response!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I fixed it like this

```
#innerExPan > * {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 50px;
}
```

And added the id to the

```
<v-expansion-panel-content id="innerExPan">
...
```

Comment: If you can provide some info about your case, maybe I'm able to help you out!

Comment: well I use a `v-expansion-panel` and I'd like to remove the padding of the `v-expansion-content__wrap` class. I tried all the above but the padding is always still there and can't be overriden. It really destroys my layout :(

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [VueJS deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to override the styling for the content wrap as follows. The approach will depend on whether you are using a pre-processor such as Sass/Scss or not.

As the Vue deep selector docs state:

> Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse `>>>` properly. In those cases you can use the `/deep/` or `::v-deep` combinator instead - both are aliases for `>>>` and work exactly the same.

### When using CSS

Use `>>>` to access the `v-expansion-panel-content__wrap` class.

```css
.v-expansion-panel-content>>> .v-expansion-panel-content__wrap {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

### When using SASS/SCSS

Use `::v-deep` to access the `v-expansion-panel-content__wrap` class.

```
.v-expansion-panel-content::v-deep .v-expansion-panel-content__wrap {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

### Only modifying specific expansion panels

You can also add custom classes/ids to further narrow down on what expansion panel you would like to style. For example:

```
<v-expansion-panel-content id="expansion-panel-content-1">
```

could be specifically modified as follows:

```css
#expansion-panel-content-1::v-deep .v-expansion-panel-content__wrap {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

#### Versions I'm using

Using Vuetify `2.5.x` with NuxtJS `2.15.x`

Comment: ` .v-expansion-panel-content::v-deep .v-expansion-panel-content__wrap {
  padding: 0 !important;
}`  is definetely working with vuetify 2.0

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you!

Comment: perhaps obvious if you look at the vue doc linked in this answer, but ensure that you put these changes inside `<style scoped> .... </style>` in your component, otherwise it will not be applied

Comment: Great answer, works with v2.6.x too 

Answer (score 3):

Use Vuetify Sass variable `$expansion-panel-content-padding`

See [Vue documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)

If you are using Nuxt, modify [variables.scss](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#customvariables)

Comment: how to "use" the variable?

Comment: @xetra11 added link to Nuxt documentation

Comment: Unfortunately this changes the layout for *all* expansion panels, how would it be possible to only change the padding for a specific expansion panel?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Veutify 3:

**Step 1**: Install
[webpack-plugin-vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-vuetify) or [vite-plugin-vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-vuetify)
then enable it in your bundler configuration.

**Step 2**: On your `vite.config.ts` add
`vuetify({ autoImport: true, styles: { configFile: 'src/scss/settings.scss' } }),`

**Step 3**: create `settings.scss` file on 'src/scss'

**Step 4**: Add this on `settings.scss`

```
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
    $expansion-panel-text-padding: 0px,
);
```

Restart npm / clear browser if change did not reflect